# Run command before pulling from SVN in TeamCity

Tags: teamcity

I'm having an issue with TeamCity, which relates to the fact that it runs the source control step before it runs the build steps. My project is a windows service, so there are complications with this.

TeamCity often decides to delete the entire contents of the project directory, even though I have the clean build option unchecked. However, since this is a windows service this does not fly, as when trying to delete the dll's it errors out since they're in use:

**Error while applying patch: Failed to delete: F:\PathToService\bin\Release\Library.dll**

The most frustrating part is that the dll's aren't even under source control, TeamCity seems to have a mind of its own and decides to delete them anyway.

Is there a way to get around this, to be able to run a build step BEFORE doing the svn checkout so that I can stop the windows service first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was to split up each service into a separate working directory. That prevents teamcity from deleting the dll's.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to set up your CI environment so it uninstalls the windows service once you are done testing it. I am not aware of Teamcity pre-checkout hook.

Comment: Negative.. the services need to be used, as this is a development environment.